# Update a passbook pass via php

Tags: passbook

I created a pass via PHP and tried it on the iOS simulator and on my iPhone and everything is working fine.

Now I'm stuck with the task "update my pass" the problem here is that I don't get any payloads back to my Server.

I have a AlphaSSL Cert. on my Server running This is the JSON file for the Pass:

JSON:

```
{ 
    "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.XXXXXXX.musterkarte",
    "formatVersion": 1,
    "organizationName": "Melters Werbeagentur GmbH",
    "teamIdentifier": "XXXXXXXX",
    "serialNumber": "test",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(240,240,240)",
    "logoText": "Hi, there!",
    "description": "testpass",
    "storeCard": {
        "secondaryFields": [
            {
                "key": "balance",
                "label": "BALANCE",
                "value": "$7.36",
                "changeMessage": "change your balance to %@"
            },
            {
                "key": "name",
                "label": "NICKNAME",
                "value": "hello"
            }

        ],
        "backFields": [
            {
                "key": "id",
                "label": "Card Number",
                "value": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    "barcode": {
        "format": "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
        "message": "test",
        "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1",
        "altText": "test"
    },
    "locations" : [
        {
            "latitude" : 51.222294,
            "longitude" : 6.792051,
        }
    ],
    "authenticationToken":"72aa48d08db9a379f147e38fb23a3901",
    "webServiceURL":"https://melters-server.com/passbook_update/"

    }
```

and this is my webservice index.php:

```
$request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));



if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST"

    && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])

    && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 'ApplePass') === 0

    && $request[2] === "devices"

    && $request[4] === "registrations") {



    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);



    $device_id = $request[3];

    $pass_id = $request[5];

    $serial = $request[6];



    // Catch the JSON post and decode it

    $dt = @file_get_contents('php://input');

    $device_token = json_decode($dt);

    $device_token = $device_token->pushToken;

    if (!$device_token) die('No Token Found'); // Token wasn't found



    $sql="INSERT INTO token (id, token) VALUES (1, '".$device_token."')";



    mysql_query($sql,$link);

    exit;

}

?>
```

The Problem is after I added a new pass to my phone, the database remains empty.

and I visit

https://www.melters-server.com/passbook_update/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber

then I get this Infos in the Browser:

GET
443
Array ( [0] => passbook_update [1] => version [2] => devices [3] => deviceLibraryIdentifier [4] => registrations [5] => passTypeIdentifier [6] => serialNumber )

Comment: Double check that the super global $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORiZATION'] is populated.  Chances are that your server config does not support that variable and so your if condition is not firing.  If it doesn't check for the PHP function apache_headers, and if that does not exist you can write your own function to grab the authorization header.

Comment: thanks for your tips, but in fact I removed the IF-Condition, only kept SQL-Statement. The database still remains empty. Ich have seen nearly all your comments for improving my code. So I doubt, perhaps no rest-style requesting from my iphone. What do you think? PS.I used tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass to build a Pass.

Comment: Follow your console logs as you install the pass - ifyou have Passbook additional logging on the device, you will see the device making the call to your webservice.  Also, double check you have webServiceURL and authenticationToken properly defined ;-)

Comment: in logs: always passd[3526] <Warning>: NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it appears that your `webServiceURL` your server certificate is self signed or the certificate chain cannot be validated.

If I run your cert through [this validator](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://melters-server.com/), it implies the latter.

In developer options on your test device (Settings->Developer), turn on "Allow HTTP Services" under PassKit Testing and use a HTTP `webServiceURL`, or alternatively double check the certificate chain for the SSL certificate on your server.

Comment: thanks a lot, in my opinion, the problem perhaps was a missing intermediate cert on the server side, now I am looking forward to some answers from my network service provider.

Comment: thanks again! problem： a missing intermediate cert on the server side